# Impala query failed for -compute incremental stats databsename.table name

Tags: impala

We are scooping data from `netezza` to `hadoop` non-partitioned tables and then from non-partition to partitioned  with insert overwrite method. After this we are running compute incremental stats for databasename.tablename on partitioned tables but this query failed for some of the partitions with error

> Could not execute command: compute incremental stats  and No such file or directory for some file in partitioned directory.

Answer (score 2):

You can run a refresh statement before computing stats to refresh the metadata right away. It may be necessary to wait a few seconds before computing stats even if the refresh statement return code is 0 as past experience has shown that metadata is still refreshing even after a return code is given. You won't typically won't see this issue unless a script is executing these commands sequentially.

```
refresh yourTableName
compute stats yourTableName
```

As of Impala 2.3 your can also use the alter table recover partitions instead of refresh metadata or repair table.

```
alter yourTableName recover partitions
compute stats yourTableName
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.We are running the invalidate metadata before running the stats statement but it was not working but when we tries refresh tableName before compute incremental stats tableName then it started working fine.

Comment: I improved the answer after coming across this situation myself. Repairing the table works well to update the metastore with new partitions.